# swap elements in array2D java

Tags: java

I am making a game.  Objects fall in this game. I intend to make this "fall" happen by swapping elements in a 2D array. Each element is a object that holds a color.

I search through all elements.

[code in here](http://codepaste.net/od5en5)

It should swap.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Correct me if i am wrong, but is it not swapping like this?

```
object A,

object B,

temp c = B,

B = A,

A = c,
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] and post that _here_, so the code is in the question itself.

Comment: Post the code in the question; no links.  I don't see any swapping going on in the link.

Comment: Please stop writing and saying "basically" and "so".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post the relevand part from your code and answer on it

```
        Int x = currentTile.getX()/50;
        int y = (currentTile.getY()+1)/50;

        CellPane botTile = board[x][y];
        if (botTile.getBackground().equals(Color.BLACK)){
            board[x][y].setBackground(currentTile.getBackground());
            board[currentTile.getX()/50][currentTile.getY()/50].setBackground(botTile.getBackground());
        }
```

botTile holds a reference to the same object (board piece) as board[x][y]. You check for the color of the botTile and replace it with the one on the currentTile. This means the the object referenced both by botTile and board[x][y] now has a new color. This means the old color was lost since you didn't save it in another variable. You should have done something like this

```
        CellPane botTile = board[x][y];          
        if (botTile.getBackground().equals(Color.BLACK)){
            Color oldColor = botTile.getBackground; 
            board[x][y].setBackground(currentTile.getBackground());
            board[currentTile.getX()/50][currentTile.getY()/50].setBackground(oldColor);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you divide the value with 50 the y value will not increment unless value is 50, 100 and so on... 
Assign y as below:

```
int y = 1 + currentTile.getY()/50;
```